# Formatting Date and Time with Timezone Abbreviation

Tags: magento2.4.5, timezone, datetime, dateformat

I have overridden the `formatDateTime` function of the `\Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\Timezone` class in Magento 2 to display the timezone abbreviation along with the formatted date. However, I noticed that when using the 'z' pattern, it only returns the abbreviation without the full date.

I want to show date like `Aug 9, 2023, 5:28:31 AM (EDT)`

Here's the overridden method:

```php
public function formatDateTime($date, $dateType = IntlDateFormatter::SHORT, $timeType = IntlDateFormatter::SHORT, $locale = null, $timezone = null, $pattern = null): string
{
    // Call the parent method to get the formatted date
    $formattedDate = parent::formatDateTime($date, $dateType, $timeType, $locale, $timezone, $pattern);
    
    // Get the timezone abbreviation
    $timezoneAbbreviation = parent::formatDateTime($date, $dateType, $timeType, $locale, $timezone, 'z');

    // Concatenate the timezone abbreviation to the formatted date
    $formattedDate .= ' (' . $timezoneAbbreviation . ')';

    return $formattedDate;
}
```

Is there any alternative method or pattern that can be used to obtain the full date along with the timezone abbreviation in a single call to the `formatDateTime` function? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I will share the formatDate directly with the object manager.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$objDate = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime   \DateTime'); 
$date = $objDate->gmtDate(); 
$newDate = date("M,d-Y h:i:s A e", strtotime($date));
```

show the below link for the date formatDate you want to.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rF5Bg.png

Comment: Thanks for you answer but i want it based on timezone selected for store and not in `UTC` it should be like `EDT`